# On Duplicate Key Update syntax still duplicates my data

Tags: mysql

I understand this question might have been asked, but i tried using the solutions i found here and they didn't work for me. I need to update data in my database if the email column exists, if not it should insert a new record.
Here is my code below.

```
       <?php

    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $db = 'mbf';

    $dbconn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    mysql_select_db($db);



    $dat = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->modify('+4 weeks');


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];

          $dat = $_POST['date'];
          $ghdate = $_POST['ghdate'];
             $amount =    $_POST['amount'];
            $iniamount = $_POST['iniamount'];
           $outamount = $_POST['outamount'];
         $ghamount = $_POST['ghamount'];




         $query = "INSERT INTO donation (email, date, ghdate, amount, 
   inamount, outamount, ghamount) VALUES ('$email', '$dat', 
   '$ghdate','$amount', 
 '$iniamount', '$outamount', '$ghamount')
         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
email='$email', date='$dat', amount='$amount', inamount='$iniamount', 
outamount='$outamount', ghamount='$ghamount'";


if(mysql_query($query))
 {
 echo "<script>alert('Donation of $amount was successful');</script>";
}
 else
 {
 echo "<script>alert('FAILED TO INSERT');</script>";
 }

 }


?>
```

it does not update the email column rather it inserts a new record.

Comment: Is the email column defined as unique (or a primary key)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement works only if any field value violates UNIQUE / PRIMARY KEY constraint. Make sure the email field has UNIQUE constraint in the table schema.